# linking angular ng-click to open new page and passing param:

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

Here when user clicks edit button, I need to open a new page and also make rest call to populate that page with the param passed in.

Comment: Html:
<button type="button" ng-click="employeesController.editEmployeeTraining(employee)" title="Edit Employee></button>

Here when user clicks edit button, I need to open a new page and also make rest call to populate that page with the param passed in.

Comment: This should really be handled by something like ui-router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to know how to set up a link that takes you to a new page with access to the params you're sending. There are a few ways, depending on what modules you're using.

I recommend working with [ui.router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), but if you aren't using that, you can check out how to do it with ngRoute [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams).

If you're using ui-router, you can do this:

```
<a data-ui-sref="newPage(employee)">Edit Employee</a>
```

When the user clicks the link, it will take you to `newPage`, with the param **employee**.

In your newPage controller, you can include `$state` as a param, and then access this employee object.

```
app.controller('newPageController', ['$state', '$http', function ($state, $http) {

    var employeeData = $state.params.employee;

    //Make REST calls here
    $http({
      url: 'REST url',
      type: 'POST',
      data: employeeData
    }).then(function (res) {
       //success, etc
    });


}]);
```

Also, if you're new to Angular, I recommend the [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) on their site. It covers how to do routing.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using ngRoute and I was able to get to the new page with the parameter, I am having problem accessing the results from my API call..  ds.controller('employeeTrainingsEditController',
    function (EmployeeTrainingsAPI, $scope, $routeParams) {
        $scope.employeeId = $routeParams.employeeId;
        //var employeeData = $state.params.employeeId;


        EmployeeTrainingsAPI.employeeTrainings.query({empId: $scope.employeeId}, function (result) {
            $scope.trainings = result;
        });
    }
);

Comment: @Lokesh Okay, we need to do some debugging. Put a console.log in the callback function to make sure results looks like what you think it is supposed to. Sometimes it can be results.data or something like that, depending on your service. Secondly, if you're working with Angular's built in $http, then you'd want to write it like this: EmployeeTrainingsAPI.employeeTrainings.query({ empId: $scope.employeeId }).then(function (result) { $scope.trainings = result; }, function (err) { //error handling console.log(err); });

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and really appreciate your help. I was doing bad calls and I corrected those. Now it is working. It is making ReST call twice and I am not sure why it is making twice. Otherwise I am good. It is light weight call and I debug and see.